# wrap the root component in a <Provider>,or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, react-testing-library

I want to test component by **unit test** , I don't know how to **render** the component , it makes an error. I can use only "**React-testing-library**"

Error : Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(BaseSignUp)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(BaseSignUp) in connect options. [image]

Answer (score 2):

As your component uses your Redux state, you need to wrap it with a `Provider`.

For example like this

```js
  const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
    // you could just use your normal Redux store or create one just for the test
    <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  );
  render(<BaseSignup />, { wrapper: Wrapper });
```

Comment: I have an error again , error==>  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

Comment: You also really have to pass a `store` in there.

Comment: Please refer: https://www.30secondsofcode.org/articles/s/testing-redux-connected-components

Official Doc: https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#connected-components

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a different generic render wrapper to resolve these issue as majorly all the component ll require the store access

For eg: I have created this wrapper and exported it with name as rtlRender

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import ReduxStore from "../redux/store";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const rtlRender = component => render(<Provider store={ReduxStore.store}>
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    {component}
  </QueryClientProvider>
</Provider>)

export default rtlRender
```

and now in my test file I use this rtlRender

```
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import NewUsers from './NewUsers'
import rtlRender from '../../../utils/rtlRender'

describe('New User', () => {
  test('Proper Text', () => {
    rtlRender(<NewUsers userDetails={[]} />)

    const addUserHeading = screen.getByText('Add user')
    expect(addUserHeading).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
})
```